# Easier way to add rows with totals for groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

How could I add rows  with the sum of `VL-FOB_real` for each `CO_ANO-niv100-subsector` group in an easier way? I couldn't figure how to use `add_rows` and the like to do so, only by creating a new dataframe and then appending it.

Here is what I have done:

```
df <- structure(list(CO_ANO = c("1996", "1990", "1993", "1993", "1994", 
                                "1992", "1995", "1995", "1996", "1995", 
                                "1994", "1990", "1989", "1992", "1995"), 
                     CO_UF = c("32", "45", "45", "36", "55", "99", "36", 
                               "34", "14", "25", "53", "41", "41", "41", "16"), 
                     niv100 = c("2210","1530", "210", "3210", "1530", "2610", "2210", 
                                "2630", "1030","1020", "3020", "3020", "410", "2510", 
                                "1520"), 
                     subsector = c("11","8", "1", "7", "8", "13", "11", "13", "4", "5", 
                                   "13", "13", "2","13", "8"), 
                     VL_FOB_real = c(1, 2, 3, 
                                     1, 4, 5,
                                     5, 6, 7, 
                                     6, 8, 9, 
                                     10, 11, 11)), 
                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA,-15L))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           

df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(CO_ANO, subsector, niv100) %>%
  summarise(VL_FOB_real = sum(VL_FOB_real)) %>%
  mutate(CO_UF = 'Total')

df <- bind_rows(df1,df)
```

Comment: This seems pretty easy... 2 lines to sum by group, 2 lines add the rows with an appropriate identifier. You could put it all in the same pipeline after the mutate with `%>% bind_rows(df)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I would do what you have done to add rows for each group but for the purpose of demonstrating way to use `add_row` here's an answer :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df %>%
  group_split(CO_ANO, subsector, niv100) %>%
  map_df(~add_row(.x, CO_ANO = first(.x$CO_ANO), subsector = first(.x$subsector),
     niv100 = first(.x$niv100),VL_FOB_real = sum(.x$VL_FOB_real), CO_UF = 'Total'))

#  CO_ANO CO_UF niv100 subsector VL_FOB_real
#   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>           <dbl>
# 1 1989   41    410    2                  10
# 2 1989   Total 410    2                  10
# 3 1990   41    3020   13                  9
# 4 1990   Total 3020   13                  9
# 5 1990   45    1530   8                   2
# 6 1990   Total 1530   8                   2
# 7 1992   41    2510   13                 11
# 8 1992   Total 2510   13                 11
# 9 1992   99    2610   13                  5
#10 1992   Total 2610   13                  5
# … with 20 more rows
```

The only benefit I see of this approach is you get `"Total"` row for each group immediately after the group unlike in `bind_rows` where you get all `"Total"` rows together.

Answer (score 2):

This groups the rows and then modify each group using `adorn_totals`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>%
  group_by(CO_ANO, CO_UF, niv100) %>%
  group_modify(~ adorn_totals(.x, where = "row"))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 30 x 5
# Groups:   CO_ANO, CO_UF, niv100 [15]
   CO_ANO CO_UF niv100 subsector VL_FOB_real
   <chr>  <chr> <chr>  <chr>           <dbl>
 1 1989   41    410    2                  10
 2 1989   41    410    Total              10
 3 1990   41    3020   13                  9
 4 1990   41    3020   Total               9
 5 1990   45    1530   8                   2
 6 1990   45    1530   Total               2
 7 1992   41    2510   13                 11
 8 1992   41    2510   Total              11
 9 1992   99    2610   13                  5
10 1992   99    2610   Total               5
# ... with 20 more rows
```

Another thing to try is the following which gives somewhat different output.  It splits the input into groups and applies `adorn_totals` separately to each group giving a `c("tabyl", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")` object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
library(purrr)

df %>% 
  group_split(CO_ANO, subsector, niv100, CO_UF)  %>%
  map_df(adorn_totals)
```